# Scrambling sentences on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that scrambles the order of sentences. The program must take an input file and scramble it into an output file. However, when the sentences are scrambled, they should be numbered according to their original order. For example,

**Input**

```
I love apples  
I love candy  
I love God
```

**Output**

```
2:I love candy

3:I love God

1:I love apples
```

I'm really not sure how to begin, so if you can provide me with ideas or a way to approach this problem or what functions and methods i should be using then that would be very great.

Comment: I've added an answer which I've tested -- see my second answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be having trouble with the other answers so here is a complete solution which I've tested so it should work:

```
from random import shuffle

finput = 'path/input.txt'
foutput = 'path/output.txt'

with open(finput, 'r') as fin, open(foutput, 'w') as fout:
    sentences = fin.readlines()

    #add the order using enumeration
    sentences = list(enumerate(sentences))
    shuffle(sentences)
    for i, sentence in sentences:
        fout.write("{0}: {1}".format(i + 1, sentence))
```

Comment: I have also tried your code however i get this weird error, the only thing i changed was obviously the files:
The Input file im testing on contains:

first line

second line

third line

fourth line

and the output is blank 

the error is:
 line 262, in shuffle
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()

Comment: first line and the other lines are on different lines, I just could't write it like that here

Comment: I've tested in Python 2.7x and it works. Searching on StackOverflow I found a similar issue that might be related to Python 3.x because zip no long returns a list but an iterable. Try surrounding the 'zip' with 'list' like this 'list(zip(...))'. That should convert it to a list.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think my comment above will work for you, but you will see in my answer now i use 'list(enumerate(sentences))' which basically does the same thing as zip but it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array `sentences`:

```
#zip in the original order
sentences = zip(range(len(sentences)), sentences)    
random.shuffle(sentences)
for i, sentence in sentences:
   print "{0}: {1}".format(i, sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
  suffixes = []
  for i,line in enumerate(infile):
    line = line.strip()
    prefix, suffix = line.rsplit(' ', 1)
    suffixes.append((i,suffix))

  random.shuffle(suffixes)
  for i,suffix in suffixes:
    print("%d:%s %s" %(i, prefix, suffix))
```

Comment: I tried to study and understand your code however when i got to the function random.shuffle, although i never used it i know what it does however when i tested it (i changed your code a bit so i can test on it) i get random is not defined as a global variable, am i using it wrong?

Comment: @user2971015: `random` needs to be imported. Check out the edit

Comment: i can put import random under a function right? or does it have to be outside or before the random.shuffle command?

Comment: @user2971015: It's usually a good idea to put all your imports at the top of a file

Comment: suffixes.append(i,suffix)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'  

I checked to see if the the input file was not overwritten to become blank, however i do not understand this error? is it saying there is no data to append to suffixes???

Comment: Try using suffixes.add(...). The error is stating that the class 'set' does not define a method 'append'. You can view all of the methods (and attributes) of set (or any class) by doing 'dir(set)'.

Comment: line 265, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing this the error i get when i corrected it like u said, looks like there is something wrong with using set but i am lost right now

Comment: @user2971015: don't use a set. Use a list instead. Check out the update

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import shuffle

def scramble(infile, outfile):
    with open(infile) as f1, open(outfile, 'w') as f2:
        myrows = list(enumerate(f1, 1))
        shuffle(myrows)
        f2.writelines(('%-4d: %s' % r for r in myrows))

scramble(__file__, '/tmp/scrambled.txt')
with open('/tmp/scrambled.txt') as sf:
    print ''.join(sf)
```